# Reproduce a questionnaire preference table in LaTeX

Tags: tables, circles, questionnaire

I'd like to reproduce this table in a LaTeX document:

[image]

but I have no idea of how to do it. I've tried to create a table but it becames too large and I don't know how to reproduce the circles.

Here is a MWE that could be useful:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l|lllll|}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Per niente importante}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Poco importante}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Neutro/ indifferente}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Abbastanza importante} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Molto importante/ fondamentale}}  \\ 
\cline{2-6}
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Chiarezza grafica}                               &                                                                         &                                                                   &                                                                        &                                           &                                                                                   \\
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Facilità di utilizzo}                            &                                                                         &                                                                   &                                                                        &                                           &                                                                                   \\
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Qualità delle informazioni}                      &                                                                         &                                                                   &                                                                        &                                           &                                                                                   \\
\textcolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.2}{Aggiornamento in tempo reale dei dati contenuti} &                                                                         &                                                                   &                                                                        &                                           &                                                                                   \\
\cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Do you just want to reproduce the table as it is in the image or do you want to be able to fill in the pdf version later? e.g. do you want clickable radio buttons?

Comment: I just want to reproduce the table as it is in the image. I only want to display the questions, nothing clickable.

Comment: Are you also interested in the alternating background colors for each question?

Comment: It is not strictly necessary, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The following should get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\newcommand{\mycric}{\textcolor{gray}{\faCircle[regular]}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\rowcolors{1}{gray!30}{gray!15}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X*{5}{0c}}
\rowcolor{gray!5}                                                         
& \makecell{Per niente\\ importante}
& \makecell{Poco\\ importante} 
& \makecell{Neutro/\\ indifferente} 
& \makecell{Abbastanza\\ importante} 
& \makecell{Molto\\ importante/\\ fondamentale}  \\ 
Chiarezza grafica                               & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric \\
Facilità di utilizzo                            & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric \\
Qualità delle informazioni                      & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric \\
Aggiornamento in tempo reale dei dati contenuti & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric & \mycric \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much